# move a CALayer (add animation)

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, calayer

well I have a CALayer `layer` and I would like to move it, with a CADisplaylink. Like :

```
layer.center=CGPointMake(layer.center.x + 10, layer.center.y + 10);
```

but I can't use `center` or `position` for the layer.Here is my problem, I want to make it move like it was a uiimageview.

Comment: Why can't you use center or position?  Why not just change frame?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To move layer try to use this method

```
-(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    layer.position = point;
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

Comment: but with this method it's impossible to detect collision.Because after I want to make the layer collide :/

Comment: @jeanbernard no, it still is completely possible to detect a collision with any other object on the screen - have a look at CALayer.presentationLayer

Comment: well it is a bit hard for me to understand how can we detect a collision with a CABasicAnimation, and can you explain more what is CALayer.presentationLayer